# Format timezone to +-#### instead of +-##

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-format, timezone

I am curious if there is a way to configure Postgres (9.1+) to format the TZ part of a "timestamp with time zone" as +-####, just like PHP's date.format method does using "O".

PHP [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> O | Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours | Example: +0200

As requested an example:

```
create table example (time1 timestamp with time zone);
insert into example values ('2000-01-01 00:00:00+0200');
select * from example;
         time1          
------------------------
 1999-12-31 23:00:00+01
(1 rows)

-- How can I return the time as it was inserted (with it's timezone).
select time1 at time zone 'CEST' from example;
      timezone       
---------------------
 2000-01-01 00:00:00

-- This is the correct time, 
-- but I would like to attach the timezone to it
-- and return '2000-01-01 00:00:00+0200'
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the time zone? What is the current output you're getting? From what query?

Comment: @CraigRinger Fair enough, I hope the example I added will do.

Answer (score 2):

The `to_char` function, as the first choice to format dates, is quite limited with time zones. According to [Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) in the documentation we have `TZ` and `tz` and they'll output a time zone name, not a offset against GMT.

You may use `extract(timezone_hour from timestamptz_expression)` to get the offset as a signed number of hours and `extract(timezone_minutes from timestamptz_expression)` to get the number of minutes that comes with it. This offset is [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) as:

> The time zone offset from UTC, measured in seconds. Positive values
> correspond to time zones east of UTC, negative values to zones west of
> UTC. (Technically, PostgreSQL uses UT1 because leap seconds are not
> handled.)

Be aware that there are two conflicting conventions for the sign, east of Greenwich or west of Greenwich. You want to check that the sign is what you're expecting, otherwise invert it.

Another word of caution related to your edit:

> - How can I return the time as it was inserted (with it's timezone).

Postgres will never know the offset that the timestamp had when it was inserted, it's lost on insertion. What is returned to a SQL client is always the current offset depending on its  current time zone. In order to keep the original time zone, you'd need to store it in an additional column.